# I need to format text from mongodb about certificate and get only the common name

Tags: mongodb

I need to create a query to return only part of a string on mongodb. The main problem is that I cannot use javascript.

Here are the kind of data that I have on my database.

```
"issuer" : "CN=CA-Intern-xxxxxx, DC=prbbr, DC=xxxxxx, DC=xxxx"
"issuer" : "/DC=xxxx/DC=xxxxxx/DC=prbbr/CN=CA-Intern-xxxxxx"
"issuer" : "CA-Intern-xxxxxx"
```

Thx

I tried to use the query below without success.

```
db.certificate.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "issuer_formatted": [{ "$split": ["$issuer", ","] }, 0]
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "issuer": { "$arrayElemAt": [{ "$split": ["$issuer", ","] }, 0] }
    }
  }
])
```

I need to get the result like this:

```
{ "_id": "localhost.xxxxxx.corp_443", "issuer": "CN=CA-Intern-xxxxxx" },
{ "_id": "houston.xxxxxx.corp_443", "issuer": "CN=CA-Interna-xxxxxx" },
{ "_id": "quasar_quasar_443", "issuer": "CN=quasar" },
{
  "_id": "atlanta.xxxxxx.pre.corp_443",
  "issuer": "/DC=corp/DC=xxxxxx/DC=atlanta/CN=CA-Intern-xxxxxx"
}
```

Comment: Post your output in proper JSON format.

Comment: {
        "_id" : "localhost.xxxxxx.corp_443",
        "issuer" : "CN=CA-Intern-xxxxxx"
}
{
        "_id" : "houston.xxxxxx.corp_443",
        "issuer" : "CN=CA-Interna-xxxxxx"
}
{ "_id" : "quasar_quasar_443", "issuer" : "CN=quasar" }
{
    "_id" : "atlanta.xxxxxx.pre.corp_443",
    "issuer" : "/DC=corp/DC=xxxxxx/DC=atlanta/CN=CA-Intern-xxxxxx"
}

Comment: I solved this using a RegEx from javascript on client side. Thx for your help @Fanpark ;-)